# 'ascii' codec can't encode character error when saving list of tuples to file

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have a list of tuples, which I would like to save to a file. I normally solve this error with `.encode('utf-8')` but as I do have a tuple with integers in it, this does not seem to work.

My data looks like this:

```
lis=[[(0, u'good', 19, u'quality', 1),
  (1, u'smells', 13, u'product', 0),
  (1, u'better', 14, u'packaging', 1),
 [(3, u'error', 6, u'vendor', 0)]]
```

If I run my code

```
with open("./Results.csv","w") as f:
    for k in range(0, len(lis)):
        for line in lis[k]:
            strs=str(k)+" "+" ".join(str(x)) for x in line)
            f.write(strs+"\n")
```

I get the ascii code error. If I use `str(x.encode('utf-8'))` in the code instead Iget a different error, namely:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

It would be great, if you could help me solve this issue.

Best
Alex

Comment: what happens if you make the string you are joining on a unicode string? u" ".join(unicode(x))

Comment: (can you add a python-2 or python-3 tag to your question depending on which you use? When dealing with encodings, the two versions differ a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the call order backwards; you want

```
str(x).encode('utf-8')
```

... though the `str()` will probably bump into the same error if you are passing it things which may or may not be Unicode, and encoding a `str` isn't necessarily well-defined anyway; you should probably use

```
unicode(x).encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the `'ascii' codec can't encode character` error because you're calling `str()` on a Unicode string that has non-ASCII chars in it.

In Python 2.x, `str()` will try to encode the Unicode to bytes using the ASCII codec. Therefore, you should never use `str()` on Unicodes. Instead, you could use `.encode()` with a codec as you've tried. You've then got further problems because `x` isn't always a string - sometimes it's a `int` that does not support encode/decode. A you have Unicode strings already, you should convert `int`s to Unicode strings also. Existing Unicode strings, will be happy.

Really, if you find yourself using `.encode()` or `.decode()` in the middle of your code, then you know you're doing something wrong. Use a **Unicode sandwich** instead - Decode and encode at the edges of your code. For you, have `open()` encode for you by using the `io` module's `open`, which auto encodes.

There's some other Python features you can use to make your code readable, such as `str.format` and `+=` format. Putting it all together, it makes a much more readable and flexible code:

```
import io
lis=[
     [
      (0, u'good', 19, u'quality', 1),
      (1, u'smells', 13, u'product', 0),
      (1, u'better€', 14, u'packaging', 1)
    ],
    [
      (3, u'error', 6, u'vendor', 0)]
    ]

with io.open("results.csv","w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    counter = 0

    for k in lis:
        for line in k:
            concat = u" ".join(unicode(x) for x in line)
            outline = u"{counter} {concat}\n".format(counter=counter, concat=concat)
            f.write(outline)
        counter += 1
```

See, no fiddling with `.encode()`!

Output:

```
0 0 good 19 quality 1
0 1 smells 13 product 0
0 1 better€ 14 packaging 1
1 3 error 6 vendor 0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `str(x).encode('utf-8')` and not str(x.encode('utf-8'))
2. use `for k in lis` instead of `for k in range(0, len(lis))`
3. use `for line in k` instead of `for line in lis[k]`
4. most likely you have syntax error in `" ".join(str(x)) for x in line)` should be --> `" ".join(str(x) for x in line)`

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use Python2, you can do the following:

- convert anything to a unicode string
- encode the unicode string obtained

  ```
  ...
  strs=str(k)+" "+" ".join(unicode(x).encode('utf-8') for x in line)
  ...
  ```